# Absolute Value in Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, absolute-value

I'm trying to solve this integral problem but I'm a bit confused as to how to evaluate the absolute value portion of it. For context, $a$ is a positive constant.

$$
\int_{-a}^{a}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-t^{2}}+|a+3 t|+a\right) d t
$$

Comment: Absolute values are piecewise linear. Try splitting it into two linear integrals.

Comment: $|a+3t| = a+3t$ when $a+3t\ge 0$, and similarly, $|a+3t| = -(a+3t)$ when $a+3t<0$. The limits of integration tell you that $-a < t <a$, from this, which values of $t$ make $a+3t\ge 0$ and which values make $a+3t<0$?

Comment: Once you have figured out where $a+3t>0$ and $<0$ then by linearity of the integral you can write $$ \int_{-a}^{a} = \int_{\{a+3t\ge 0\} \cap (-a,a)} + \int_{\{a+3t<0\}\cap (-a,a)} $$ to get two integrals, each without the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

$| a+ 3t|=
\begin{cases}
 3t+a & 3t+a\geq 0, (t \geq -a/3)\\
-(3t+a)& 3t+a<0,  (t < -a/3)
\end{cases}$

Now you divide the integral

\begin{align}
&\int_{-a}^{a}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-t^{2}}+|a+3t|+a\right) d t =\\
& \int_{-a}^{-a/3}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-t^{2}}-a-3 t+a\right) d t +\int_{-a/3}^{a}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-t^{2}}+a+3 t+a\right) d t\\
&= \int_{-a}^{-a/3}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-t^{2}}-3 t\right) d t +\int_{-a/3}^{a}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}-t^{2}}+3 t+2a\right) d t
\end{align}

you complete the solution now.

Comment: You have a slight error when solving for the value of $t$ since $$3t+a \ge 0 \implies 3t \ge \mathbin{\color{red}{-}} a$$

Comment: @RobertLee thanks, I will correct it.